# Заполнение даты события по группе пользователей

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Есть таблица csv следующего вида:

| user_id | event_type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | install | 01-01-2021 |
| 001 | login | 02-01-2021 |
| 001 | login | 04-01-2021 |

Нужно создать новый столбец install, который будет заполняться датой из столбца date по всем строкам в группировке по user_id, при этом дату нужно брать с из события event_type='install'.
Если у пользователя нет event_type='install', то заполнять None

Итоговая таблица должна быть такая:

| user_id | event_type | date | install |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | install | 01-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 |
| 001 | login | 02-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 |
| 001 | login | 04-01-2021 | 01-01-2021 |

Comment: Можно было бы заполнить минимальной датой в группировке по user_id, если бы выполнялось условие, что у пользователя всегда есть event_type=='install' и оно имеет минимальную дату, но это не так.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'event_type': ['install', 'login', 'login', 'login', 'login', 'login'],
     'date': ['01-01-2021', '02-01-2021', '04-01-2021', '01-02-2021', '02-05-2021', '04-06-2021']})
df = df.merge(df.loc[df.event_type.eq('install'), ['user_id', 'date']], on='user_id', how='outer',
              suffixes=('', '_y')).rename(columns={'date_y': 'install'})
print(df)
```

```
   user_id event_type        date     install
0        1    install  01-01-2021  01-01-2021
1        1      login  02-01-2021  01-01-2021
2        1      login  04-01-2021  01-01-2021
3        2      login  01-02-2021         NaN
4        2      login  02-05-2021         NaN
5        2      login  04-06-2021         NaN
```